# OOXML\ODF libraries

Tags: .net, qt, openxml, odf

I want to create a .NET application, which would allow me to perform semantic markup of OOXML (Custom XML Part and ContentControls) and ODF (RDF metadata) documents. I am looking for suitable libraries. For OOXML, the ideal choice is Open XML SDK 2.0. But there are not so many .NET libraries to work with ODF (I only found AODL and ODF.NET) and they do not quite fit. I can’t use Java library in .NET code (?).

The remaining options for this seem to be UNO (which I also do not want to use) and Qt. Will Qt be suitable for my purposes? Will I be able to organize the interaction between .NET and Qt? Or can I use something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the right answer to your problem... but you can use Java libraries in .NET Framework. Yes! It's possible through the use of [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/).

Comment: Thank you, Sedric. I'll try to use this approach.